# Request headers not sent from Service Worker

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, service-worker

I'm trying to fetch a web service from a Service Worker. This service is a JSP secured with basic Apache authentication, so I must provide the credentials to authenticate in the request headers. The following request works just fine from the main window:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Received a push message', event);

  event.waitUntil(
    fetch(ONLINE_SITE_ENDPOINT, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic btoa(auth info)'
    }
    }).then(function(response) {
        //process response
    }).catch(function(err) {

    })
  );
});
```

That code is into an event.waitUntil() scope, into a function called from a 'push' event listener. However, the same exact call fails with a 401 (Unauthorized). The Network panel from the developer tools shows the headers are not being sent:

```
OPTIONS /latest-new.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: {an accessible host}
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/service-worker.js
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Is there something missing here? or it just can't be achieved from a Service Worker?

Some extra info: just can't use XMLHttpRequest since it is 'Not defined' on the service worker scope.
The headers on the JSP before retrieving the JSON:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
```

**UPDATE:** definitely there is something with the authentication headers from the service workers, since the requests to non-secured URLs does not fails. The same service without Apache authorization works as expected.

Comment: I don't understand what your comment means about `XMLHttpRequest` as it is absolutely supported in webWorkers (see [this webWorker description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) for doc on that).  Can you post all the relevant webWorker code?  We need to see where something is going wrong and you've not posted enough code here.

Comment: @jfriend00 just updated the code to show you the listener, the process code is irrelevant (it just shows a notification with the info retrieved into the JSON). I don't know why, if I try to do `var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` into the web worker I got a 'not defined' error. Outside the web worker it works just fine. Google chrome 43.0.2357.134, ubuntu

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what `event.waitUntil()` or `fetch()` are doing as those are not standard functions (they must be coming from some library).  What I'm hoping to see is the code that actually sets the headers that you say are missing and be able to follow enough of the flow to see how the request is being formed and sent.  You're only posting higher level code that doesn't show any of the details where the problem is likely occurring.

Comment: @jfriend00 those functions are not from a library, check this out: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch
I based my code on that sample: https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo/blob/master/app/service-worker.js

Comment: Which exact headers are missing from the request?

Comment: @jfriend00 those I'm setting on the fetch() - Authorization and Accept

Answer (score 1):

You should set as allowed headers also **accept** and **authorization**

```
response.setHeader(
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
  "x-requested-with, accept, authorization"
);
```

also body of the response for "OPTIONS" request should be empty (it is not necessary indeed, but there is no use case for body in such response) and `Content-length:` should be 0 (zero)

Please note, that this request should not be passed to application (you can, but not need)

Comment: Thanks @eicto, tried it but unfortunately the headers are still not being sent. Cant get the response since the request itself is rejected at the Apache because it lacks the authentication headers.

Comment: You should not require auth for OPTIONS

Comment: In fact there will be two requests 1st - OPTIONS and 2nd - GET

Comment: So the first request will always be without the headers I want to send? I don't see this one at the Network profiler (Chrome dev tools)

Comment: Yes, use fiddler or wireshark to see

Comment: Ok, but the same fetch() call from the main window works as expected and the headers are there, it seems like the request from the service worker is different.

Answer (score 0):

Pass {"credentials": "include"} as the param to the fetch() call.

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/