# Fetch() in service worker js not able to send request headers?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker, fetch-api

My code for the same.I am calling fetch() but the request in network and server has no request headers like cookie. I found one more post for this [Request headers not sent from Service Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567649/request-headers-not-sent-from-service-worker) but it was not able to solve my problem.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function (subscription) {
      fetch('/user/get-notification', {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token,
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(subscription)
      }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.status != 'success') {
          console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);
          throw new Error();
        }

        return response.json().then(function (data) {
          var title = data.title;
          var message = data.message;
          var icon = data.image;

          return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
            body: message,
            icon: icon
          });
        });
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error('Unable to retrieve data', err);
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: i have same problem but i dont think what is the use of user/get-notification in above code.

Comment: what do you mean by self.token?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well after browsing official documentation of service worker, I noticed addition of

> credentials: 'include'

in fetch enable to send request headers.Thanks for the support though.

Answer (score 4):

To include cookies you need to add the `credentials` field to your request:

```
fetch('/user/get-notification', {
  credentials: 'include', // <-- To include cookies!
  mode: 'no-cors',
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(subscription)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Headers is an interface, you can provide new set of options to it, by initializing. Something like this:

```
 headers: new Headers({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.token,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 })
```