# Is it possible to access token in service-worker fetch request headers?

Tags: javascript, request, http-headers, fetch, service-worker

I want to send a `GET` request including a token `"Authorization"` header to my nodejs server. For this, I use this function client-side:

```js
// Do a secured GET API request and return response object
async function getJSON(url) {
    try {
        // Send request
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            headers: { Authorization: localStorage.getItem('token') }
        });

        // If something went wrong
        if (!res.ok) {
            // If token is invalid
            if (res.status === 401) {
                // Logout
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
                location.replace(`/?msg=${dict.get('expired-session')}`);
            }

            // Return an object with error message and status code
            return { error: res.statusText, status: res.status };
        }

        // Else return response object
        else return await res.json();
    } catch (err) {
        // Return an object with error message
        return { error: err.message };
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I use a service worker to cache requests as they are made and I don't want API requests to be cached, so I though I could just check for the `"Authorization"`'s presence:

```js
// Fetch event
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => e.respondWith(respond(e)));

async function fetchAndCache(req, cache_name) {
    const { url, headers } = req;
    console.log({ url, headers });

    // Fetch request
    const fetch_res = await fetch(req);

    const is_get = req.method === 'GET';
    const is_api = req.headers.Authorization;
    const is_cahing_domain = cache_domains.some(domain => req.url.includes(domain));

    if (is_cahing_domain && is_get && !is_api) {
        // Open cache and save a cloned result
        const cache = await caches.open(cache_name);
        cache.put(req, fetch_res.clone());
    }

    return fetch_res;
}

async function respond(e) {
    if (!use_cache) return fetch(e.request);

    // Try to get response from cache
    const cached_res = await caches.match(e.request);

    // If response is found, return it
    if (cached_res) return cached_res;

    // If request is not found, try to fetch it
    return await fetchAndCache(e.request, 'main');
}
```

Unfortunately, the logs show empty headers:

[image: Dev tools empty headers log screenshot]

Even though the server does get the token and the cached (since the condition does not work) request also includes it:

[image: Dev tools cache response screenshot]

I searched for a few hours, tried every solutions in similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567649/request-headers-not-sent-from-service-worker) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437047/fetch-in-service-worker-js-not-able-to-send-request-headers)) but none worked. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Authorization header. But the right way to print headers is via method 2. It seems like you are using method 1.

```
console.log("Try 1 to print headers.");
console.log(request.headers);

console.log("Try 2 to print headers.")
for (const pair of event.request.headers.entries()) {
  console.log(pair[0]+ ': '+ pair[1]);
}
```

[Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxXyD.png)

Answer (score 0):

`Headers {}` does not mean that the header is empty. It means that it contains an object which is not printed in detail in your console.

You can access the Authorization header as follow:

```
console.log('AuthorizationHeader is:',headers.get('Authorization'))
```